# PHP key-value array push

Tags: php, arrays, key-value

```
$test = array (
    "test1"  => array("a" => "1", "b" => "2", "c" => "3")
);
```

I have an array like above.
ı want to push its values in a loop. How can it be possible ? Could you please tell me ?

Comment: Push them where? What do you want as the end result?

Comment: Like `$test['test1'][$newKey] = $newValue;` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have to push new values you can just do like this:

```
$test['test1']['newkey1'] = 'newvalue1';
$test['test1']['newkey2'] = 'newvalue2';
$test['test1']['d'] = '4';
```

or

```
$test['test2'] = array(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have specified to which you want to push your values.

```
// array to push content
$newArray = array();

// loop through first dimensional of your array
foreach ($test as $key => $hash) {
    // your hash is also an array, so again a loop through it
    foreach ($hash as $innerkey => $innerhash) {
        array_push($newArray, $innerhash);
    }
}
```

the array will contain only "1", "2", "3". If you want a different output, please reply which output you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_push()` function to push the elements in an array. `array_push()` treats array as a stack, and pushes the passed variables onto the end of array. The length of array increases by the number of variables pushed.

```
$test = array (
    "test1"  => array("a" => "1", "b" => "2", "c" => "3")
);

$test[] = "YOUR ELEMENT";

or

array_push($test, 'YOUR DATA', 'ANOTHER DATA');


/* If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use
$array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function. 

array_push() will raise a warning if the first argument is not an array. 
This differs from the $var[] behaviour where a new array is created. */
```

Function Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score -1):

Just use foreach!

```
foreach($test['test1'] as $key => $value){
    echo "$key = $value";
}
```

Comment: since it's a 2D array, you have to use 2x foreach loop. At first run, the $value field contains an array.

Answer (score -1):

You can use foreach.

```
foreach ($test as $key => $value) // Loop 1 times
{
    // $key equals to "test1"
    // $value equals to the corespondig inner array

    foreach ($value as $subkey => $subvalue) // Loop 3 times
    {
        // first time $subkey equals to "a"
        // first time $subvalue equals to "1"
        // .. and so on
    }
}
```

If you are expecting the first subarray to be only one as your example you can skip the first loop:

```
foreach ($test["test1"] as $subkey => $subvalue) // Loop 3 times
{
    // first time $subkey equals to "a"
    // first time $subvalue equals to "1"
    // .. and so on
}
```

**Edit: If you want to push data inside you can't use the local variables as $key and $value. You can use $key to reffer the original array variable. For example:**

```
foreach ($test["test1"] as $subkey => $subvalue) // Loop 3 times
{
    // changing current value
    $test["test1"][$subkey] = "new value";

    // pushing new member
    $test["test1"][] = "some value"
}
```

Comment: So this will help him loop through the values but he wants to push new values to the array.